# Make a copy of a row in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with rows [Item_name varchar(255) Primary key] and [Price varchar(255)], and a few others. I want to copy the row price into the same table, with a new name "old_price". How do I do this? I did some research and tried this:

```
INSERT INTO item_list (item_list.price) (SELECT item_list.price FROM item_list WHERE item_name = item_name);
```

I get the error "Field 'Item_name' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: First please check if you want to do Update operation or Insert !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE  item_list  SET old_price=price ;
```

first update the table with column name old_price.

Comment: Please capitilize letters for SQL keywords.